# How to cover trigger.oldmap.get area in test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I wrote test class for a trigger and covered 72%.
I jst want to know how to cover Trigger.oldmap.get area.

```
if(oppObj.Key_Negotiator__c ==null && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id).Key_Negotiator__c !=null && OppContactRoleMap.get(oppObj.id).size() < 4)
            {

                 Opportunity OldoppObj=Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id);     
                 system.debug('--OldoppObj-->>'+OldoppObj);    
                 OppId.add(OldoppObj.id);
                 ContactId.add(OldoppObj.Key_Negotiator__c); 

            }
            else if(oppObj.Key_Negotiator__c!=null && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id).Key_Negotiator__c==null)
            {

                newContactRoleList.add(new OpportunityContactRole (ContactId=oppObj.Key_Negotiator__c, OpportunityId=oppObj.Id, Role='Key Negotiator'));
            }
```

Test class:

```
@isTest(seealldata=true)
public class TestCreateContactRole {
    static testmethod void UpdateAccountSubscriptionEmail()
    {   
        Account a = new account();
        a.name='test';
        insert a;

        contact con =new contact();
        con.LastName='Test';
        con.AccountId=a.Id;
        insert con;

        opportunity opp=new opportunity();
        opp.AccountId=a.Id;
        opp.name='test';
        opp.StageName= 'Lead';
        opp.CloseDate= System.today(); 
        opp.Contact_Person__c=con.Id;
        opp.Key_Negotiator__c=con.Id;
        opp.Design_Offices__c=a.Id;
        opp.Partner_in_Charge__c=con.Id;
        opp.Project_Design_Leader__c=con.Id;


        insert opp;
        //update opp;

        //Test.starttest();
        opportunity opp1=new opportunity();
        opp1.AccountId=a.Id;
        opp1.id=opp.id;
        opp1.name='test';
        opp1.StageName= 'Lead';
        opp1.CloseDate= System.today(); 
        opp1.Contact_Person__c=con.Id;
        opp1.Key_Negotiator__c=con.Id;
        opp1.Design_Offices__c=a.Id;
        opp1.Partner_in_Charge__c=con.Id;
        opp1.Project_Design_Leader__c=con.Id;
        update opp1;
        //Test.stopTest();
    }



}
```

[image]

Comment: Your question would be much easier to answer if you posted your existing test class and told us which lines of code in trigger aren't covered (mark them in your code as we can't tell). Since `Trigger.oldmap.get(oppObj.Id)` is used throughout your trigger, without seeing your existing unit test code, one might conclude that you've not written one at all.

Comment: Hi @crmprogdev I updated test class.

Comment: Best practice suggestion - remove `SeeAllData=true`  - this will only lead to ruin somewhere down the line during a deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have two test methods. In essence, you need to create another one for where the `Key_Negotiator__c==null`. You already have one for where the `Key_Negotiator__c!=null`. Leave that field empty when creating data in the new method and you should have what you need.

After inserting your opportunities, your test should have a:

```
test.startTest();
// lines where you make changes to the opportunity records
update opp;

test.stopTest();

// query opp to get new values
// system.asserts that new values are as expected
```

To help support your test requirements, you may need to add additional contacts.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get test coverage, like crmprogdev said, you should have separate unit tests to test various scenarios.

Now in order to get into that other section, it looks like Key_Negotiator__c must originally be null and then moving to a non-null value.

2 ways to do this:

1) Remove/comment this line:

```
opp.Key_Negotiator__c = con.Id;
```

2) Null out the value before you do anything else after your insert:

```
insert opp;
opp.Key_Negotiator__c = null;
update opp;

Test.starttest();
```